# Change Format Number of an array. Doubles with Points in an Array

Tags: arrays, vba

I have an array of Doubles. These Doubles have no point (Ex: 100000). I want to put the point --> 100.000. How can i achieve this?

I have tried:

```
FormatArrayTemp(j, i) = Format(FormatArrayTemp(j, i), "#,##0")
```

The problem is, it returns a string, and i want still the doubles.

Any help please?
Thanks a lot
Albert

Comment: you wrote above you want to put **100.000** , is it a dot `.` or a comma of thousand `,` ?

Comment: where do you "want to put the points" into? In a worksheet cells? If so, just keep doubles as they are in your array and then format worksheet cells

Comment: No. In a worksheet i have doubles with points. i create an array from these range of doubles, and the point gets lost. I want to have an array with doubles and points.
In worksheet: 800.000 (double), in my array: 800000 (double), what i want: in my array 800.000 (double). I have just achieved: in my array (800.000 (string))

Comment: Doubles don't have format. They are numbers. Only the string representation of a number possesses a format. It isn't clear what you even *mean* by your question. Are you e.g. converting a string to the number one hundred thousand  when you want to convert it to a one hundred?

Comment: Pardon? Numbers don't have format? Is this the same? a) 1000000 b) 1.000.000 c) 1M d) 1,0 M e) 1e6 etc.I want to show in the legend of a powerpoint presentation (generated by vba) the format 1.000.000 and not 1000000. Thanks for your replies

Comment: This guy had the same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653492/format-datatable-values-in-vba

Comment: I guess there's no solution. Problem: Change format in the table data legend of a chart with VBA. Problem: even in excel you can not do that. There's no option :( you can just change the format of the cells, and then it works. so the question remains again. change the format in the array with doubles

Comment: I can reformulate the question: I want to create a chart in powerpoint with a table legend. To create this chart i use an array full of doubles. I want to show in the table legend the thousand separator. How can I do it? :) is this way understandble?